# zabuto calendarでクリックイベントをjsonの値によって変えたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap(+jQuery)で動く，[zabuto calendar](http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/index.html)というプラグインがあります。

デフォルトでの動きは，

(1)マンスリーカレンダー表示
(2)JSON形式のイベントデータがあると，該当日付に背景色を表示。クリッカブルになる。
(3)クリッカブル日付をクリックすると，モーダルウィンドウが降る。モーダルウィンドウ内には，JSONデータやHTMLを記述可能。ハイパーリンクも書けるので，それをクリックで別ページに遷移(例:該当日付の詳細データページに飛ぶ，などできる)。

となっています。

(2)にてJSONデータの値で，「badge」という値がtrueだと，背景色＋日付文字色反転ハイライトになるのですが，このtrue値をフックして，

・{badge:true}なら，モーダルウィンドウが降ってくる
・{badge:false}なら，モーダルウィンドウは降らず，日付にハイパーリンクを仕込んで，そのページに飛ぶ

という改造を施したいのですが，行き詰っています。

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/action.html はご覧になりましたか？

クリックされた時の action を書き換えることができるようです。
サンプルでは、`hasEvent` 値を見て分岐しているので、似たような処理で行けるのではないでしょうか？

```
var hasEvent = $("#" + id).data("hasEvent");
```